# the first dropdown is selected it would remove the selected item from the next dropdown

Tags: javascript

i  have 7 dropdown boxes in html. They will all get populated the same data. What I am trying to do is when the first dropdown is selected it would remove the selected item from the next dropdown. So, if you Have data: A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I in one dropdown if I select B in the first drop down then in the next dropdown it should only show A,C,D,E,F,G,H,I and so on up to 7 dropdowns. I dont know what would be the best way to approach this in JavaScript. Thanks for your help in advance
Sample Code:

```
   <select>
   <option value="1">1</option>
   <option value="2">2</option>
    <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>

     <select>
     <option value="1">1</option>
     <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
    <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
     </select>

     <select>
      <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
    </select>
```

Comment: Hey, did you want to post the sample code?

Comment: he's asking for approach, I don't think he started coding yet

Answer (score 2):

You could use attribute targeting. I'll assume jQuery, because why not.

```
$("select").change(function() {
   $(this)
       .next("select")
       .find("option").removeAttr("disabled")
       .end()
       .find("option[value=" + $(this).val() + "]").attr("disabled", "disabled");
})​
```

Again, this is just an approach so if you post code we can make better guesses.

**Updated**
Here's the JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/FaVdu/1/

Comment: In your example, if I click all three options in the first dropdown, the third dropdown loses all of its options.

Comment: Updated - to be honest, the question isn't really very specific.

Answer (score 1):

How about something like this **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/LrfNw/)**? The selected options of each drop down is disabled in every other one. This allows you to change an options without removing it.

```
$('select').change(function() {
    var ary = new Array();
    $('select option:selected').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val().length > 0) {
            ary.push($(this).val());
        }
    });
    $('select option').each(function() {
        if ($.inArray($(this).val(), ary) > -1) {
            $(this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
        } else {
            $(this).removeAttr('disabled');
        }
    });
});​
```

Comment: What am I supposed to glean from that?

Comment: May be i'm using wrong jquery libraries.... Using this on my page  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.microsoft.com/ajax/jquery/jquery-1.4.2.min.js"></script>

Comment: It strange I tried u r ../jquery-1.7.2.min.js code(using dreamweaver 8) but still it doesn't work... I'm not sure were i'm doing wrong..

Comment: The same option can we try on javascript instead of jQuery.. If you have any ideas please keep post... Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Hi here the solution for above question check it

```
 <script type="text/javascript">
        function cleanOptions(selectedOption) {
            var val = selectedOption.options[selectedOption.selectedIndex].value;
            if(val!="select"){
            //Clear all items
            $("#drop2 > option").remove();

            //Add all options from dropdown 1
            $("#" + selectedOption.id + "> option").each(function () {
                var opt = document.createElement("option");
                opt.text = this.text;
                opt.value = this.value;
                document.getElementById("drop2").options.add(opt);
            });

            //Remove selected
            $("#drop2 option[value='" + val + "']").remove();
        }
        }
    </script>

<select id="drop1"  onchange="cleanOptions(this)">
  <option value="select" selected>---select---</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
</select>

<select id="drop2">
  <option value="select" selected>---select---</option>
  <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
  <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  <option value="vw">VW</option>
  <option value="audi" >Audi</option>
</select>
```